# Variables in python aren't their value inside a for loop

Tags: python, list, function, binary, nested-lists

I am making a function that converts integers to binary number with the bin() function then removes the '0b' adding it to an output nested list where the output should look like:

`[['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'],['0','0','0','0','0','0','0','1'],...]`

*A list of lists with 8 digits as strings*

However, when the for loop that adds the leading zeros(see below) runs, I get 128 leading zeros. I checked the leading zeros value and it's correct. What would I have to change in order for it to output what it's supposed to?

Thanks

```py
def convert_to_binary(num_list,func_list):
    ...
    for i in range(len(num_list) - 1):
        leading_zeros = 8 - len(func_list[i])
        #print(leading_zeros)
        for j in range(leading_zeros):
            func_list[j].insert(0,'0')
    print(func_list)
```

Comment: I suspect the problem is with how you're creating the original `func_list` argument. Show how you're calling the function.

Comment: My guess is that all the elements of `func_list` are references to the same list.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the length of `num_list`, but then getting the value from `func_list[i]`? How are these two inputs related? And why subtract 1 from the length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I have updated the code based on the comment:

> 'the intended goal of the function was to make it so you gave it a list of integers and another empty list that the function would fill.'

```py
def convert_to_binary(num_list, func_list):
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        # Collects the binary string removing '0b'
        binary_string = bin(num_list[i])[2:] 

        # Break the string into a char array (for loop shorthand)
        temp = [char for char in binary_string] 

        # Add the binary array to func_list
        func_list.append(temp) 

        # Pad with 0's        
        leading_zeros = 8 - len(temp)
        for j in range(leading_zeros):
            func_list[i].insert(0,'0')
    print(func_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_list = range(0, 10)
    func_list = []
    convert_to_binary(num_list, func_list)
```

---

**Original**

I am not quite sure what is going on in the `...` before the input - or at the sate of `func_list` however I have made these assumptions:

`num_list` = int list of number (eg. 1 - 10)

`func_list` = list of binary string: where `func_list[i] = bin(num_list[i])` with the 0b removed from the front of the string.

With the above conditions - the following will do what you have asked:

```py
def convert_to_binary(num_list, func_list):
    for i in range(len(num_list)):
        leading_zeros = 8 - len(func_list[i])

        # Build an array of the char's in the func_list index
        # can be done in shorthand with temp = [char for char in func_list[i][k]]
        temp = []
        for k in range(len(func_list[i])):
            temp.append(func_list[i][k])

        # Replace the binary string with binary char array at func_list index
        # e.g. '1' becomes ['1']
        func_list[i] = temp

        # Add 0's to the front of the char array 
        for j in range(leading_zeros):
            func_list[i].insert(0,'0')
    print(func_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_list = range(0, 10)

    # Create an array of Binary strings 
    # (for each value in num_list - removing '0b' from the front)
    func_list = [bin(i)[2:]for i in num_list] 

    convert_to_binary(num_list, func_list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1']]
```

Comment: Thank you. Two things, the intended goal of the function was to make it so you gave it a list of integers and another empty list that the function would fill. Also, what is `func_list` in the if statement equal to. What is happening there? Thanks!

Comment: Okay - I can alter my answer given the new information. What is the line of code you would like clarity on? I would be happy to explain :D

Comment: @ForestCayden I have updated my original post with comments (which will hopefully answer your question from the comment) and I have added another solution given the new details. Hope this is what you are looking for :D